# How to deform/curve a mesh without getting sharp edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I am having an issue. I want to curve a concrete plinth mesh that I made for a project of mine. However, whenever I use the curve tool on the plinth two edges show up perpendicular to the curve. I've tried to subdivide the face to little avail.

[image: Despite the curve, there is still a seam/crease.]

[image: Bottom view]
[image: Internal view]

Comment: Your model is to high density to make large-scale adjustments to. You need to figure out a way to remake it with lower resolution and then bump it up once you get the base shape you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue I found out is to select the "Beauty" modifier whenever you fill the loop mesh after you convert the curve to a mesh but before you solidify. This method uses large faces rather than trying to turn the entire mesh into thin prisms. Using this method I have had no further issues. Any adjustments can simply be made by undoing back to the curve and manipulating control points.

[image: Without Beauty modifier]

[image: With Beauty modifier]